# Not possible to place actions with SSJS in Action Bar of XPage OneUI?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I¨m working quite a while with XPages, and this must be a rookies question:
I want to place my common actions like "Save Document", "Edit", "Cancel" in the Action Bar in the upper part of the OneUI of the extlib (Place Bar). 
I succeeded to get any basic (or other) nodes in the place bar, but I can only give them client side JS, not the usual server side JS which I gave to a button.

Am I missing sth? Of course I searched (here + google), but cannot find any answer for this simple question.

Hope you can "push me into the right direction" ....

thx, Uwe

Comment: I second Alex. Go revisit your questions and accept the answers

Comment: Sorry for leaving things open - I now already have accepted (and upvoted) the answers which solves problems or are helpful. 
Answers which were not successfull are left open. 
Sorry if I still missed any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the buttons "Save" and "Edit" as `xe:basicLeafNode` to the action bar

```xml
<xe:applicationLayout ... >
    ...
        <xe:this.placeBarActions>
           <xe:basicLeafNode
              label="Save"
              submitValue="save">
           </xe:basicLeafNode>
           <xe:basicLeafNode
              label="Edit"
              submitValue="edit">
           </xe:basicLeafNode>
```

and define the code you want to execute as **SSJS** code in `xe:applicationLayout`'s `onItemClick`event

```xml
  <xp:eventHandler
     event="onItemClick"
     submit="true"
     refreshMode="complete">
     <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            var s = context.getSubmittedValue();
            if (s=="save") {
                print("write code here for save");
            } else if (s=="edit") {
                print("write code here for edit");
            }
        }]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xe:applicationLayout>
```

You can test in onItemClick event with `context.getSubmittedValue()` for basicLeafNode's submitValue and get to know this way which button was clicked.

Comment: Hi Knut, this looks great (for me :-)!
And it's already working with my buttons ....

As far as I understood the event handler, it means that every click on any item will trigger my code?

Kind Regards, Uwe

Comment: Yes, every click on such a button executes the code in onItemClick event and there you have to figure out which button was clicked.

Comment: Thx Knut - this works quite well :-)
I hope this is not a performance eater, when every click is checked against a ssjs function.